# Somebody agrees with somebody else on doing something

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Is the following sentence pattern, and the [sentence](http://infomarket.md/en/social/The_government_of_Moldova_agreed_with_trade_unions_on_starting_talks_on_gradual_increase_of_the_minimal_wage_next_week_) I read on the Internet, grammatically correct?

Somebody agrees with somebody else on doing something.

> The government of Moldova agreed with trade unions on starting talks
>   on gradual increase of the minimal wage next week.

Which ones of the sentences below are correct in this case? (I convinced my brother that he will donate to a charity.)

> My brother agreed with me on donating to a charity.
>
> My brother agreed to me on donating to a charity.
>
> My brother agreed to me  donating to a charity.
>
> My brother agreed to me donate to a charity.

Comment: Who is donating? --just you, or both of you? Note that the object of *donate* is the gift, and you donate **to** a recipient.

Comment: @StoneyB I convinced my brother that he will donate to a charity with me.

Comment: *on* means *about* here.

Answer (score 3):

You can "agree to" do something, or "agree with" someone, or with someone "agree on" something.  However I can see the use of these can be tricky.  For example it is more natural to say:

> We agreed **to** donate to charity

rather than

> We agreed **on** donating to charity.

So I would write your example as:

> My brother agreed **with** me that we should donate to charity.

But then you can say:

> But we couldn't agree **on** how much to donate.

The pattern seems to be that if you would normally use the verb, you would *agree to (verb)* but otherwise *agree on (adverb or phrase)*, but I might be missing some exceptions and perhaps an overarching rule.

Comment: Thank you. How about the sentence I excerpted?

Comment: I guess that's an exception, although I would have rewritten it: *"The government of Moldova agreed with trade unions **to** start talks next week on a gradual increase of the minimal wage."* I guess this reporter's editor was on a break.

Answer (score 2):

In the pattern you are using

> *someone* agrees **with** *someone/something*
>   *someone* agrees **to** *something*
>   *someone* agrees **to do** *something*

also

> *someone* agrees **on** *something*

to signify what is being agreed upon.

> I agree **with** you on your need for a new bike.
>   *you have told me you need a new bike and I think you are correct*
>
> I agree **on** getting you a new bike next Christmas.
>   *I agree that getting a new bike should be done, but not until next Christmas*
>
> I agree **to get** you a new bike next Christmas.
>   *I will get you a new bike next Christmas*

So,

> *Your brother* agreed **with** *me* on donating to a charity.

is the correct variant.  In your first sentence

> The *government of Moldova* agreed **with** *trade unions* on starting talks on gradual increase of the minimal wage next week.

is the first pattern.